# Codeigniter Pagination Links are not working with boostrap pagination class

Tags: codeigniter

Pagination links created with bootstrap class "pagination" are not working. Links created without adding bootstrap class working fine. Here is my controller Code

```
    $config ['base_url'] = base_url () .'adv/index';
    $config ['total_rows'] = $result->num_rows();
    //$config ['uri_segment'] = $segment;
    $config ['per_page'] = 5;
    $config ['num_links'] = 5;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<liclass="page-item">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active"><a href="page-link">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['links']=$this->pagination->create_links();
    $category=$this->adv_model->adv_get_paginated_data($segment,5);
    $data['category']=$category;
$this->global['pageTitle'] = 'Media : Communiation';
    $this->loadViews("adv_view", $this->global,$data, NULL);
[View Image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDcVX.png
```

Comment: not working? can you expand on that?

Comment: nothing happening . like not clickable.thank you for your response.

Comment: again, not enough detail. what exactly is echoing?

Comment: on view page links are generating. but on click anchor tag is not sending request to controller.

Comment: show the generated html as an edit to your question

Comment: fyi you have a typo here `<liclass="page-item">` missing space and this is strange syntax `<a href="page-link">` can use `#` as `href` here if you want (assuming you need it because your styles apply to `a`)

Comment: changed still not working.

Comment: by generated html, i mean the actual code that is generated for pagination; just copy-paste it from view-source